# Getting error uninitialized constant NHLSDecorator if config.eager_load = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and working on Rails 4 application. In my development.rb I have

```
config.cache_classes = false 
config.eager_load = false
```

Here is the directory structure of my application

[image]

Here is the snippet of my NHLSDecorator class

[image: NHLSDecorator class]

Here is the line from the _results_html.erb file that when run raise error

```
<% posting = Posting::Decorator.new(posting) %>
```

Now with this I am getting error that

[image: Error]

I also have `nhls/app/presenters` directory in my autopath. I also added `app/presenters/posting` directory. Here is the snapshot of my application.rb file

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/controllers/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/reports/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/searchers/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/workers/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/presenters/posting)
```

But I am getting the error. If I change `config.eager_load = true`. Then it works fine. Why I am getting this error? What can be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Basically what I did I rename the file in `app/presenters` directory to `nhls_decorator.rb`. Instead of `NHLS_Decorator`. Also in the code I changed the lines

```
class Posting::Decorator < NhlsDecorator
```

note previously it was `class Posting::Decorator < NHLSDecorator`. And also in the file `nhls_decorator.rb`

```
class NhlsDecorator < SimpleDelegator
```

note previously it was `class NHLSDecorator < SimpleDelegator`.

So renaming did the trick. Actually with debug I found that for NHLSDecorator filename rails unable to find any path. But when I changed it to NhlsDecorator then rails find the path which is `app/presenters/nhls_decorator.rb"` and loads the file.

Thanks